# Is there a way to create a multiple-item text input in html?

Tags: python, html, django, input

I'm looking to find/create some sort of html text input field where users can input multiple items.  This could either be in one text box (but ideally with a clear distinction between items) or through multiple boxes, though the number of boxes should be variable.  I can probably write something that achieves the latter, but I was wondering if anything already existed.

The result would be passed to a Django-based web app as a Python list, if that changes anything.  Push comes to shove I'll simply instruct users to enter all items in one text box delimited by commas.

Comment: You are looking for formsets with Django.

Answer (score 0):

so I understood you write you want to tokenize sort of your input, right? As the user definitely should see the different input arguments from my perspective this tool that works with [jquery](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) could be one solution. (However, the repo is already archived so it is probably not developed any further.) So after the input is tokenized you could then maybe extract the input in the django view ?

Answer (score -1):

According to what I understand, you just need a normal html input box allow user to input.

And once user submit their input, such as they input "1,2,3,4,5,6". You can just do

```
list = input.split(",")
```